# Создание триггера, на изменение первой таблицы, находя строку по id второй таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо создать триггер, который будет обновлять значение во второй таблице, когда обновилась первая.

Структуры

Первая таблица

```
id
username
ban_server
bans
```

Вторая таблица

```
id
isBanned
```

(В таблицах много столбцов, привожу только важные)

В столбце bans первой таблицы находится id второй таблицы.

ban_server - 0 или 1

isBanned 0 или 1

Необходимо если в isBanned второй таблицы, становилось 1, то в первой тоже становилось 1. Я думаю, можно брать id второй таблицы, где было поставлено 1 и искать в столбце bans первой таблицы это число. Потом проставлять в первой таблице 1.

Comment: правильно думаете. что получилось? с какой проблемой столкнулись?

Comment: проблема: не получилось реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_t1 
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE table2
SET isBanned = 1
WHERE id = NEW.id
  AND NEW.ban_server = 1;
```

Плюс то же самое на `AFTER INSERT`.